# Cordova: Firebase Error "auth/internal-error" on iOS app review

Tags: ios, firebase, authentication, cordova, review

I use Firebase-js in my Cordova app and it works without any problems on Android and iOS Devices (simulators and real devices).

But everytime I want to submit the app to the Apple Store, the review says that there is a bug and they send me a screenshot of the bug.

Looking at the screenshot, I see that Firebase throws the error "auth/internal-error" when a user tries to log in.

Do you have any idea where the error comes from?